# Add new keys and values to an existing dictionary where the keys are matched

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to calculate the cost of product `c = 20 $` and `d = 30$`. Since I have `meta data` and df as separated data frame I need to join them somehow where I can then get the price and the number of items bought for each product (e.g. `c:5`) in a dictionary for each individual id, and then calculated the price of each product (e.g. for product `c` `1 * 20`)

1. My First data frame

   ```
   Metadata  = {'product_name': ["c", "d"], 'product_price': [20, 30]}
   Metadata = pd.DataFrame(data=Metadata )
   ```
2. My second data frame

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 'product':[{'c':1}, {'d':3}, {'c':5, 
   'd':6}]})
   ```

`Edited`

3. My attempts:
   So I thought I need to get access to the keys and then use them for later for matching.
   I start with converting the `Metadata` table into a dictionary:

   ```
   def get_product_price_dictionary(Metadata):
       product_info = Metadata
       product_price_dict = dict()
       for d in product_info.to_dict('records'): 
           p_name = d["product_name"]
           p_price = d["product_price"]
           product_price_dict[p_name] = p_price
       return product_price_dict
   test = get_product_price_dictionary(Metadata)
   test
   ```

Output:

```
{'c': 20, 'd': 30}
```

Then I get the keys inside my data frame.

```
list_keys = []
df_dic = df['product']
for i in range(len(df_dic)):
    if df_dic.iloc[i] is not None:
        each_dic = df_dic.iloc[i]
    for key, value in each_dic.items():
        list_keys.append(key)
list_keys_uique = list(set(list_keys))
list_keys_uique[0:5]
```

`Output`

```
['c', 'd']
```

I have recently get started working with python and now, I am really stuck in working with dictionary! to get the column called `product_cost` in the df data frame.

And now I do not know how to precede with it!!!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You're asking for a personal tutorial on several topics; this is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune the OP has been updated with the relevant information. It is appropriate to remove down / close vote.

Comment: I don't understand why you're working this into and out of data frames.  You have two dicts that you want to merge.  You should be able to work directly from two dicts to the result you want.  Note that you have not specified that result.

Answer (score 1):

I would not turn everything to dict as Pandas is already very fast. You can search for certain values within a database using double equators together with the row name:

```
df[df['row']==key].value
```

I added a little piece of code which walks your database and calculates the total money of each transaction:

```py
Metadata  = {'product_name': ["c", "d"], 'product_price': [20, 30]}
Metadata = pd.DataFrame(data=Metadata )

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 'product':[{'c':1}, {'d':3}, {'c':5, 'd':6}]})

print (Metadata)
print (df)

for action in df['product']:
  print ('action:', action)
  total = 0
  for product in action:
    price = float(Metadata[Metadata['product_name']==product].product_price)
    print ('  product: %s, price: %.2f' % (product, price))
    print ('    count: %i, sum: %.2f' % (action[product], price * action[product]))
    total += price * action[product]
  print ('  total: %.2f' % total)
```

Console output of the above code:

```py
  product_name  product_price
0            c             20
1            d             30
   id           product
0   1          {'c': 1}
1   2          {'d': 3}
2   3  {'c': 5, 'd': 6}
action: {'c': 1}
  product: c, price: 20.00
    count: 1, sum: 20.00
  total: 20.00
action: {'d': 3}
  product: d, price: 30.00
    count: 3, sum: 90.00
  total: 90.00
action: {'c': 5, 'd': 6}
  product: c, price: 20.00
    count: 5, sum: 100.00
  product: d, price: 30.00
    count: 6, sum: 180.00
  total: 280.00
```